# React navigation (v5): custom header buttons for specific tab screen

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5

I need to put buttons on the header in tab navigation. Each tab can have different buttons in the header and the buttons need to interact with the screen itself. For example, In my travel app, in the first tab I would have map button in the header which will toggle map/list view and in the wishlist tab I would have plus button in the header.

When it's a standard screen (not tab) adding a button that interacts to the screen is easy and can be done as explained in: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/header-buttons#header-interaction-with-its-screen-component. However, that doesn't work for screens under tabs. I found this documentation https://reactnavigation.org/docs/screen-options-resolution on how to change header title and style on tab navigation but I can't find any info on how to add buttons in a way that it can interact with the screen since the component which define tabs is different than the screen component.

Comment: Currently I found a hack to update the screen header using navigation.dangerouslyGetParent().setOptions. I'm hoping there is a better and more documented way.

Answer (score -1):

You can add Tab Bar Componnet using the prop : "tabBar" in react-navigation V5. You can do like this :

```js
<Tab.Navigator
          animationEnabled={false}
          swipeEnabled={true}
          tabBar={props => <TabBarComp {...props} />}
          tabBarOptions={{
            // scrollEnabled: true,
            activeTintColor: '#3684F6', //'rgb(12,157,197)',
            inactiveTintColor: 'black',
            indicatorStyle: {
              backgroundColor: '#ACACAC',
            },
            labelStyle: {
              fontSize: 16,
              color: 'black',
            },
            style: {
              backgroundColor: 'white',
            },
            statusBarStyle: 'light-content',
          }}>
        
                  <Tab.Screen name={'tabName} component={screenName} />
        </Tab.Navigator>
```

I am also doing the same way, My Tab Bar Component looks like this :

```js
import React from 'react';
import {View, TouchableOpacity, ScrollView, Dimensions} from 'react-native';
import Animated from 'react-native-reanimated';
import {colors, fonts} from '../../res';
import {setValueBasedOnHeight, setFontSize} from '../../utils/deviceDimensions';

export const TabBarComp = ({state, descriptors, navigation, position}) => {
  const isIpad = Dimensions.get('window').width > 500 ? true : false;
  return (
    <View>
      <ScrollView
        showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
        horizontal
        style={{
          width: '100%',
          backgroundColor: colors.white,
        }}
        contentContainerStyle={{
          flexGrow: 1,
        }}>
        {state.routes.map((route, index) => {
          const {options} = descriptors[route.key];
          console.log({options});
          const label =
            options.tabBarLabel !== undefined
              ? options.tabBarLabel
              : options.title !== undefined
              ? options.title
              : route.name;

          console.log({label});

          const isFocused = state.index === index;
          console.log({isFocused});
          const onPress = () => {
            const event = navigation.emit({
              type: 'tabPress',
              target: route.key,
              canPreventDefault: true,
            });
            console.log('route.name', route.name);
            if (!isFocused && !event.defaultPrevented) {
              navigation.navigate(route.name);
            }
          };

          const inputRange = state.routes.map((_, i) => i);
          const opacity = Animated.interpolate(position, {
            inputRange,
            outputRange: inputRange.map(i => (i === index ? 1 : 0.5)),
          });

          return (
            <TouchableOpacity
              accessibilityRole="button"
              accessibilityStates={isFocused ? ['selected'] : []}
              accessibilityLabel={options.tabBarAccessibilityLabel}
              testID={options.tabBarTestID}
              onPress={onPress}
              style={{
                backgroundColor: colors.whiteColor,
                borderBottomColor: colors.grayColor,
                borderBottomWidth: isFocused ? 0.5 : 0,
                flex: 1,
                justifyContent: 'center',
              }}>
              <Animated.Text
                style={{
                  color: colors.grayColor,
                  fontSize: setFontSize(14),
                  paddingHorizontal: 20,
                  alignSelf: 'center',
                  fontFamily: fonts.avenirNextBold,
                  paddingVertical: 10,
                  minWidth: '35%',
                  opacity,
                }}>
                {label}
              </Animated.Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          );
        })}
      </ScrollView>
    </View>
  );
};
```

```js
this.props.navigation.setOptions({
      headerTitle: (
        <Text
          style={[
            {color: 'white'},
            {fontSize: 22},
            {fontFamily: fonts.avenirNextDemiBold},
          ]}>
          Privacy Policy
        </Text>
      ),
      headerStyle: {
        borderBottomWidth: 0,
        backgroundColor: colors.navBarHeaderColor,
      },
      headerTintColor: colors.whiteColor,
    });
```

Comment: I'm not sure how the code example is related to setting the *header* buttons.

Comment: In My TabBarComp, I have <Animated.Text>, here you can add Your Map Icon.. Instead of Text..

Comment: If I understand correctly the tabBar allows a way to customize the tab bar. I don't see how it's related to modifying the header of the screen which the tab is showing.

Comment: Oh, you want to change Header itself, you can do this also, when on switching the Tab, in your class Component/functional component you can add this.setOptions in componentDidMount/useEffect, I have updated the answer..

Comment: It's not working for me and I don't think it should work per the documentation: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/screen-options-resolution#setting-parent-screen-options-based-on-child-navigators-state. The docs actually give a solution for modifying the header style and label for screens shown by tabs but when it comes to adding buttons to the header which would interact with the screen itself - I didn't find a way to do that

Comment: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/headers/#updating-options-with-setoptions and see this also https://reactnavigation.org/docs/headers/#replacing-the-title-with-a-custom-component